# mysql workbench getting context help working

Tags: mysql-workbench

what do I have to do, to get the context help working in the SQLAdditions in Workbench 8.0.18?

I'm using the latest Xampp bundle, is there a better alternative maybe?

Comment: Context help should work out of the box. If that's not the case file a bug report at https://bugs.mysql.com.

Comment: Anybody else facing the same problem? Then I'd report it as bug. Otherwise I hope it's just some misconfiguration...

Comment: Your Xampp probably uses MariaDB, which is not supported by MySQL Workbench (it supports only MySQL). I think this is the reason why context help does not work.